# How to read files (with special characters) with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an (encode/decode) problem.

Although I used "utf-8" to read the file into a `DataFrame` with the code shown below, the characters look very different in the output. The language is French. I would be very happy if you can help with this, thank you in advance.

The first line of data examined

b"Sur la #route des stations ou de la maison\xf0\x9f\x9a\x98\xe2\x9d\x84\xef\xb8\x8f?\nCet apr\xc3\xa8s-midi, les #gendarmes veilleront sur vous, comme dans l'#Yonne, o\xc3\xb9 les exc\xc3\xa8s de #vitesse & les comportements dangereux des usagers de l'#A6 seront verbalis\xc3\xa9s\xe2\x9a\xa0\xef\xb8\x8f\nAlors prudence, \xc3\xa9quipez-vous & n'oubliez-pas la r\xc3\xa8gle des 3\xf0\x9f\x85\xbf\xef\xb8\x8f !"

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\gendarmerie_tweets.csv', delimiter=";", encoding="utf-8")
data.head()
```

Output:

```
    text
0   b"Sur la #route des stations ou de la maison\x...
1   b"#Guyane Soutien \xc3\xa0 nos 10 #gendarmes e...
2   b'#CoupDeCoeur \xf0\x9f\x92\x99 Journ\xc3\xa9e...
3   b'RT @servicepublicfr: \xf0\x9f\x97\xb3\xef\xb...
4   b"\xe2\x9c\x85 7 personnes interpell\xc3\xa9es...
```

Comment: Could you show the first line of the csv file which gave that output?

Comment: Use instruments like `chardet` to identify the real encoding of your data before you load it.

Comment: Really nice tool Sergey, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe for this cases you can try with different `encoding`. I believe the decoding parameter that might help you solve this issue is `'ISO-8859-1'`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\gendarmerie_tweets.csv', delimiter=";", encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

#### Edit:

Given the output of reading the file:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\gendarmerie_tweets.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1254'>
```

From python's [codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) `cp1254` alias `windows-1254` is language turkish so I suggested trying `latin5` and `windows-1254` too but none of these options seems to help.

Comment: I often use latin1, but the output explicitely contains some utf-8 encoded bytes. I would be surprised if changing `utf8` with `latin1` in OP's code would solve anything...

Comment: ISO-8859-15 helps me where the standard latin1 utf8 don't help

Comment: I believe ISO-8859-15 might be the key.

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer, but "latin1" and "ISO 8859-1" gave the same output.

Comment: Did you try ISO-8859-15? Also what did `chardet` give you?

Comment: I dont know how to use the chardet code, can you help with this?

Comment: How about simply try: `f = open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\gendarmerie_tweets.csv')` and then `print(f)` does it say something about encoding?

Comment: f = open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\gendarmerie_tweets.csv')
print(f)                                                                                       
        OUTPUT<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\gendarmerie_tweets.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1254'>

Comment: Try `latin5` please then and/or `iso-8859-9`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207774/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-emre-cihan-ates).